# Passing from java to HTML

Tags: java, javascript, html, eclipse, applet

I have i problem, I made a program in java using eclipse compilator, the thing is that It has two packages and in each package there are 3 classes i have tried to insert this code in a html file useing the applet tag but the problem is that it doesnt works, i dont know how to do it, and its quite important 
I have tried using applet tags and tried the .jar I found something like this

```
<applet codebase ="." code="zuve.ZuveApplet.class"
        archive=".jar,1.jar"
        height="1000" width="1000"/>
```

Comment: It's quite unclear what are you asking... could you explain it better or provide more info?

Comment: "it doesnt work" Can you copy the full text of the error message and paste it here?

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you do a short tutorial on Applets:

http://java.about.com/od/webapplications/ss/firstapplet_3.htm

It is quite easy and you may made a misstake at one of those important points:

- Compile your source: This includes a.) having your .java files beeing transformed to .class files and b.) packaging everything into a .jar file (you can make a .zip and rename it to .jar by hand).
- Link your applet: This is done like described here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html. You want to have both of your different packages packed in ONE .jar and have that single jar defined as argument 'archive' while your argument Code has to point to your applet class (e.g. the one extending from either Applet or JApplet or something like that).

Make sure that paths are set properly, easiest way would be to have everything (the .html with the applet tag and the .jar with your applet code inside) inside the same folder.